# I have 8,244 files that i need to add a ";" to

Tags: python, java

Im trying to import data from a rng file. the data appears as:

AA
1;999.78

A2s
.98;765

within the files. when i open as csv the AA and the 1 get put in the same column and no matter what i select i cant seem to change that. So i need to batch add a ";" after the letters. These are poker hands by the way which there are 169 in each and i have over 8k files. i need them as csv to import into mysql. any suggestions would be appreciated as i dont have alot of coding experience and really am learning as im going with this project.

my end goal is to have a more user friendly app to see ranges on the fly, ive got the html down, as well as the java for a [hand grid(13x13)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okdGX.png)

now im working on getting the data which each range has a unique filename that contains a 169 hands formatted as i stated above that will populate that hand grid by coloring it. hopefully this is enough info to give you an idea as to what im doing. * TRYING* to do LOL

Comment: just replace `\n` with `;` using a text editor

Comment: 169 times each for 8000 files by hand?

Comment: Use a tool that can do that to "all files in folder". Notepad2 or notepad++ should be able to do that, not sure about vscode.

Comment: usually there's a replace all option in text editors

Comment: Get [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), open the folder the files are contained in, and replace it in all files simultaneously. Takes a second or two.

Comment: ive looked to try and find a way to do that, i use vs code to write everything else but i cant seem to find a way to do what your say @ValerijDobler can you show me a small example? i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-and-replace)

Comment: @ValerijDobler yes it worked, but it actually crashed my pc lol. i have a solid setup as well( ryzen 24 thread and 128gb ram) but it ends up freezing and causes screen lockout which i assume is due to the fact that VS has to open each file individually and change them. which i have just over 8k files. plus i would have to do multiple passes (ie. AA to AA; s to s;(which covers all suited hands) o to o;(which covers all offsuit hands) and then KK to KK;, QQ,JJ,TT,99,88,77,66,55,44,33,22 which would be 15 passes. im trying to find a way to add multiple instances to "find and replace" now.

Comment: Maybe a programmatic approach would be better because the data would be processed in serial.

Comment: @ValerijDobler yes i found a better way. i still had to make 15 passes but it took about 6 mins to do all 15. i did have some issues with the pocket pair hands like 99,88 etc as they also added ";" within the EV values. BUT..I dont need the ev values so thats ok. i used powershell and ill put the code in the "answer your question"

Answer (score 1):

So if you look at my last comment you can see that I still had to make 15 passes, but it did work and much faster than VS Code search and replace. I used Powershell and here is the code:

```
gci path*.ext -recurse | ForEach {(Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace "AA","AA;"}) | Set-Content $_ }
```

Where path = data location and ext = file extension. Inside the replace bracket the first set of "" is what your looking for and the second set of "" is what your going to replace with.

**Edit:**
The way the data is formatted I could just add a ; at the end of each line. That can be accomplished by:

```
gci path*.ext -recurse | ForEach {(Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace "$",";"}) | Set-Content $_ }
```